# How the deleted xib gets loaded?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have created a class 'abc' which a subclass of UIViewController. At the time of creating it i clicked the option for creating an xib for it automaticaly. Now the xcode creates 3 files for me
1. abc.h
2. abc.m
3. abc.xib.

Now whenever i create an object of abc class like 
abc *a=[abc alloc];

Even when i am not initialising the object with initiwithNibName and using it, it is loading the xib file. So how this xib file got associated with the abc object. And even if i deleted the abc.xib, then also it loads that xib file. I couldnt understand from where it is loading the xib file, if it it not present in the project space. And where the association of xib and controller is stored?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have u removed it from the folder also? or just a reference from the group tree?

Comment: i moved it to trash. is it the same thing as removing it from the folder?

Comment: if u delete from the group tree. u get two options.. one is remove ref and the other is move to trashl.. check if the file is still thr in ur folder

Comment: ohh yes i deleted it from the group tree. and then i selected the option move to trash. On selecting that option does it not remove the file from the folder too or do i need to remove it from folder explicitly.?

Comment: yes its working now. But i couldnt understand 1 thing. even if i have moved to trash from the group tree. still it is there in the folder. how? I mean it should get deleted from the folder also..

Comment: nope.. u have 2 options.. either just remove it from the group tree.. or remove from group tree and also move to trash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's going on is that the default implementation of `initWithNibName:bundle:` searches the Main Bundle for a Nib file that has the same name as your View Controller class. This happens whether you select the option for creating the Nib automatically or not. See [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName%3abundle%3a) documentation (the discussion portion of `initWithNibName:bundle:`).

Now the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method is UIViewController's default initializer, which means that even if you don't use it directly (say that you use `init` instead) it will get called under the hood anyway.

Finally, even if you delete the Nib file from XCode, for some reason (not sure why) it doesn't get deleted from the Main Bundle (at least in the simulator). Even if you clean & build the project it stays there. **The solution I use to get completely rid of the Nib file is to delete the App from the simulator, then clean & build again.**

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The xib is probably still in your compiled area, so you need to perform a clean to get rid of it fully. (Product >> Clean). The default init method of UIViewControllers will automatically look for a xib of the same name, which is why it's still allocating that xib. Once you clean it will stop.

Reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName:bundle:

Note this part: If you specify nil for the nibName parameter, you must either override the loadView method and create your views there or you must provide a nib file in your bundle whose name (without the .nib extension) matches the name of your view controller class. (In this latter case, the class name becomes the name stored in the nibName property.) If you do none of these, the view controller will be unable to load its view.

Comment: no i cleaned the project, even i empty caches. but it is still loading that xib

Comment: Did you delete it from the filesystem or just from your project (remove reference option)?

Comment: and if suppose i hadnt called the initWithNibName on my controoler object? Then also will it associate the nib file(that matches the name of my view Controller)with the controller?

Comment: i deleted it  using the move to trash option.

Comment: So how do you know the xib file is being loaded, exactly? You don't explain that in your question. Is something showing up on the screen you don't expect?

Comment: if i have deleted it and i am not initialising the object with any other xib, then it should show me nothing. But it is showing me all the contents of the xib.

Comment: Have you deleted the app off the simulator or device after cleaning?

Comment: sorry i ma new to ios , i dint get your last comment.. do i need to delete the application from the simulator after cleaning?

Comment: Yes, just press and hold, delete the app from the simulator, and then run it from xcode again (after cleaning).

Comment: oh yes.. it helped. thanks. But just on deleting the file from the group tree and even from the folder why it is not working? even when i empty caches.. From where it get the files?

Comment: Sometimes the xib files are cached within the executable on the device, I guess.